# activate click through mode on conky

Tags: themes, conky

Is it possible to use Conky theme as click through on desktop ?. i can use Conky as transparent. but i can't directly access files on desktop because can't click through it. Any idea ?. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the option `own_window_hints='below'`. I just removed that from my config file and it put my conky display overtop anything below it (and hence I can't "click-through").